# ISO C++ forbids declaration of ... with no type

Tags: c++, qt, header-files, maemo, qt-mobility

I'm using C++ to make a Qt mobile application for maemo.

I have my class declaration, but I get this error:

```
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QGeoPositionInfoSource' with no type
```

My code is following:

**phonehelper.h**

```
#ifndef PHONEHELPER_H
#define PHONEHELPER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGeoPositionInfoSource>


class PhoneHelper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit PhoneHelper(QObject *parent = 0);
    void GetGPSData(const char * callbackSlot);

private:
    /*
     * The error occures here on the line below */
    QGeoPositionInfoSource *gpsSource;         // PROBLEM HERE

private slots:
    void positionUpdated(const QGeoPositionInfo &info);
};

#endif // PHONEHELPER_H
```

**phonehelper.cpp**

```
#include "phonehelper.h"

PhoneHelper::PhoneHelper(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

PhoneHelper::GetGPSData(const char *callbackSlot)
{
    gpsSource = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);
             if (gpsSource) {
                 connect(source, SIGNAL(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)),
                         this, SLOT(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)));
                 connect(source, SIGNAL(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)),
                         this, SLOT(callbackSlot(QGeoPositionInfo)));
                 gpsSource->startUpdates();
             }
}

PhoneHelper::positionUpdated(const QGeoPositionInfo &info)
{
        gpsSource->stopUpdates();
        delete gpsSource;
}
```

**Project.pro**

```
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = # file1 dir1

symbian:TARGET.UID3 = 0xE0EEBE99


symbian:TARGET.CAPABILITY += NetworkServices

# MOBILITY variable.
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += location

SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp \
    phonehelper.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h \
    phonehelper.h
FORMS += mainwindow.ui


include(deployment.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()
```

What does the above error mean?

Comment: You forgot to say which line exactly triggers the error and give the exact error text. Which is kind of important.

Comment: Dear Jon.. I get error during build, the line that couses it is `QGeoPositionInfoSource *gpsSource;` in my .h file... The exact error text is presented above...

Comment: Probably `QGeoPositionInfoSource` is in some namespace (sorry, I've used QT). You could check that.

Comment: Are you sure that <QGeoPositionInfoSource> is really included and that it contains declaration for `QGeoPositionInfoSource` class? You can check it by adding forward declaration `class QGeoPositionInfoSource;` just before `PhoneHelper` class declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not see that I had to use QtMobility namespace like this `using namespace QtMobility;`

Comment: I'd recommend using `QtMobility::QGeoPositionInfoSource` not to include the whole namespace in the header.

Comment: Putting a using clause into a header file will just lead to problems down the road. Fully qualify the type name,.

Comment: You should use a forward declaration in headers, which isn't trivial for namespaces: `namespace QtMobility { class QGeoPositionInfoSource; }`. This may look weird, but it's the correct way to forward-declare namespace members.